# Почему не получается отправить координаты GPS на сервер?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, пытаюсь отослать полученные `GPS-координаты` на сервер, если их выводить в консоль то всё в порядке но когда пробую отправить их на сервер приложение падает.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER/*ТИП ПРОВАЙДЕРА*/,// НА ВХОД ЕМУ ПОДАЁМ
            1000 * 10/*МИНИМАЛЬНОЕ ВРЕМЯ ЗАПРОСА КООРДИНАТ*/, 10/*РАСТОЯНИЕ ОТОЙДЯ НА КОТОРОЕ ОБНОВЛЯЮТСЯ КООРДИНАТЫ*/, locationListener);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {//ОТКЛЮЧАЕМ СЛУШАТЕЛЯ МЕТОДА removeUpdates
    super.onPause();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}

private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        showLocation(location);
        coordinatesGPS ();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        checkDisabled1();
        checkDisabled2();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

};

private void showLocation(Location location) {
    if (location == null)
        return;

    dataGPS1 = formatLocation1(location);
    dataGPS2 = formatLocation2(location);
}

public String formatLocation1(Location location) {
    if (location == null)
        return "";
    return String.format(
            "%1$.4f",
            location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

}

public String formatLocation2(Location location) {
    if (location == null)
        return "";
    return String.format(
            "%2$.4f",
            location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

}

private void checkDisabled1() {
    dataGPS1 = "00,0000";

}

private void checkDisabled2() {
    dataGPS2 = "00,0000";

}

public void coordinatesGPS () {

    String datGPS1 = dataGPS1;

        System.out.println("Координаты =" + datGPS1);
    try {
        //----------------------------------------------
        client = new Socket("192.168.1.138"/*192.168.1.138"*/, 58000);
        //----------------------------------------------

        DataOutputStream outData = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

        outData.writeUTF(datGPS1);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Ошибка.

```
08-29 11:33:53.556 23612-23612/gpstracker I/System.out: Координаты =89,1706
08-29 11:33:53.556 23612-23612/gpstracker D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-29 11:33:53.556 23612-23612/gpstracker W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418e4c08)
08-29 11:33:53.566 23612-23612/gpstracker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: gpstracker, PID: 23612
                                                                   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1166)
                                                                   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
                                                                   at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
                                                                   at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
                                                                   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
                                                                   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
                                                                   at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:567)
                                                                   at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:128)
                                                                   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)
                                                                   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:150)
                                                                   at gpstracker.MainActivity.coordinatesGPS(MainActivity.java:137)
                                                                   at gpstracker.MainActivity$1.onLocationChanged(MainActivity.java:73)
                                                                   at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:279)
                                                                   at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:208)
                                                                   at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:224)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Может оно таким образом ругается на подключение к сети из основного потока?

Comment: Попробуйте сделать поход в интернет из AsyncTask или Service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задачи связанные с доступом в интернет, рекомендуется делать в фоне. AsyncTask или Service, например.

Так же попробуйте:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```